# Unexplainable VIRTUAL memory behavior for multi-threading code heap allocation

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory, virtual-memory

I am trying to study the effect of pthread based Multi-threading code modifications on VIRTUAL memory on a 64-bit Centos based Linux system

I am attaching a spreadsheet where the observations were made on VIRTUAL MEMORY (using Linux based top command) with increasing the number of threads and each thread is allocating 1MB each.

I am pasting C++ code used for observation (below) for the reference:

From the observations made shown in the table below, for a single thread allocating 1MB data VIRTUAL memory used is 89.824MB, for 2 threads allocating 1MB each VIRTUAL memory is 165.604MB, for 3 threads allocating 1MB each VIRTUAL memory is 235MB and then onwards VIRTUAL memory increases by 1MB per thread.

[Click here to view the table having observations made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69IwM.png)

To summarize, VIRTUAL memory starts with 89MB, becomes double after adding 2nd thread, again becomes almost double after adding 3rd thread, then increases by 1MB for addition of each thread, each allocating 1MB of heap.

Can anyone explain why is this behavior exhibited by the system ?

Please post if you need any other details. Looking forward for the help.

**Note:**
the code was compiled using g++ (g++ -o vma CODE_FILE.cpp -lpthread)
only 1MB of heap was allocated by each thread but were not populated
the generated binary size is only ~9KB (got using ls command)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

/*
  NOTE: Make sure you provide NUM_THREADS in the range (1..5)
*/
#define NUM_THREADS 5

struct thread_struct
{
    int id;
    char *msg;
};

void *thrdFunc(void *i)
{
    char *it = (char*)i;
    cout << "\nthis is thread named :"<< it ;

    char *mallocBlk = new char [1000000];
}

int main()
{
    int rc = 0;
    void *status;
    char threadNames[8][8] = { "Thread1" , "Thread2", "Thread3",  "Thread4", "Thread5", "Thread6", "Thread7", "Thread8"};

    pthread_t     threads[NUM_THREADS];
    thread_struct thrStructs[NUM_THREADS];

    cout << "\nIn Main, creating threads!" ;

    /*
       Create threads
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thrdFunc, &threadNames[i] );

        if (rc)
        {
            cout << "Thrd" << i+1 << " cant be created";
        }
    }

    /*
       Wait till all the threads complete
   */
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Done! Waiting for your input!";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the memory map for 5 threads:

> [rebaca@localhost stackoverflow]$ cat /proc/31528/maps
>   00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 20451094                           /home/rebaca/stackoverflow/vma
>   00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:02 20451094                           /home/rebaca/stackoverflow/vma
>   01784000-017a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
>   305b400000-305b420000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1703944                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
>   305b61f000-305b620000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 1703944                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
>   305b620000-305b621000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 1703944                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
>   305b621000-305b622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   305b800000-305b98a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1703966                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
>   305b98a000-305bb8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 1703966                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
>   305bb8a000-305bb8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 1703966                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
>   305bb8e000-305bb90000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 1703966                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
>   305bb90000-305bb94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   305bc00000-305bc17000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1703968                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
>   305bc17000-305be17000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 1703968                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
>   305be17000-305be18000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 1703968                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
>   305be18000-305be19000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 1703968                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
>   305be19000-305be1d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   305c800000-305c883000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1704110                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
>   305c883000-305ca82000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 1704110                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
>   305ca82000-305ca83000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 1704110                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
>   305ca83000-305ca84000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 1704110                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
>   3066800000-3066816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1704139                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
>   3066816000-3066a15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 1704139                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
>   3066a15000-3066a16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 1704139                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
>   3066c00000-3066ce8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 809560                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
>   3066ce8000-3066ee8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 809560                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
>   3066ee8000-3066eef000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 809560                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
>   3066eef000-3066ef1000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 809560                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
>   3066ef1000-3066f06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3ec000000-7fd3ec115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3ec115000-7fd3f0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f0000000-7fd3f0115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f0115000-7fd3f4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f4000000-7fd3f4115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f4115000-7fd3f8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f8000000-7fd3f8115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3f8115000-7fd3fc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3fc000000-7fd3fc115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd3fc115000-7fd400000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4032b6000-7fd4032b7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4032b7000-7fd403cb7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd403cb7000-7fd403cb8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd403cb8000-7fd4046b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4046b8000-7fd4046b9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4046b9000-7fd4050b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4064bb000-7fd4064c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fd4064db000-7fd4064de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7ffc72456000-7ffc7246b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
>   7ffc72568000-7ffc72569000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
>   ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Comment: Dump the memory map of the process.  IIRC it's `/proc/PID/maps` on Linux.

Comment: Do you really intend to have a memory leak in your function?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have updated the memory map in my question

Comment: @NathanOliver - Please suggest me does the memory leak in the code is going to affect VIRTUAL memory in any manner ?

Comment: It is certainly not gong to help.  As far as what the OS is going to do I'm not sure.

Comment: @rebaca You need to compare memory maps between runs of your test process with different numbers of threads and see what's different.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Thanks for the reply. I will compare the memory maps and update on the findings.